# error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\2.invPeluqueria\resources\views\articulos\articulocreate.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, lista

Estoy tratando de generar en un select o lista desplegable con los nombres de proveedores correspondiente a cada id que ya he traido con un input(este id es llave forane a de articulos), nunca he trabajado este tipo de listas deplegables y no se cual sea el error, he visto tutoriales pero ninguno me ha funcionado.

vista (articulo create)

```
 <div class="form-group " >
      {{Form::select('proveedor','$proveedor')}}
          <label for="id_proveedor" class="col-sm-2 amaranth" style="color:white">ID Proveedor</label>
         <select name="id_proveedor" id="inputid_aproveedor" class="form-control" >
            @foreach($proveedor as $proveedor)
                <option value="{{$proveedor->id_proveedor}}">{{$proveedor->id}}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
      </div>
```

controlador

```
 public function create()
  {
    $proveedor=['proveedor'=>proveedor::pluck('nombr_proveedor','id_proveedor')];
    return view ('articulos.articulocreate',$proveedor);
  }
```

[image: En la imagen se puede ver el articuloindex en el cual listo los articulo y se dan cuenta trae el id del proveedor mas no el nombre a seleccionar]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el mismo nombre de variable para la colección a iterar y la variable que guarda el resultado de la iteración ("$proveedor")

Prueba con :

```
@foreach($proveedor as $prov)
  <option value="{{$prov->id_proveedor}}">{{$prov->id}}</option>
@endforeach
```